# Laravel Route to Standalone WebApp

Tags: laravel, routes

I am trying to build a portal in Laravel to serve some other, standalone web apps (not built in Laravel), but I am struggling to find out how to route to these apps if I want to place them outside the public folder. 
In the past, I would use (temporary) symlinks for this kind of things, but I was wondering if Laravel provides another solution.

So, I have a folder:

```
module 
module/index.php 
module/js/whatever 
module/css/whatever 
module/img/whatever
```

and I want a route /modules/1 to link to index.php in the module-folder in such a way that the resources in this folder (js/css/img) are also accessible.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can include other PHP files with `require_once`.

**web.php**

```
Route::any('/webapp/{assets?}', 'WebAppController@index');
```

**WebAppController**

```
class WebAppController {
    public function index(Request $request) {
        require_once '../module/index.php';

        if ($request->assets) {
            // check from session if user is logged in

            // require asset as well 
            // (or download them https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#file-downloads)
        }
    }
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

Comment: Sure, but then the index.php gives a lot of 404 errors, since the resources in the subfolders are not publicly available.

Comment: But then they are not protected for unauthorised users

Comment: Yes, I need the assets to become available only after login. My question is how to do this in a sensible way: I cannot copy them runtime to a public folder, as it is then public to all other users.
Maybe a symbolic link still is the best solution (it works and is kind of safe if I remove the link after a certain amount of time), but I cannot imagine no one else wants to build this kind of solutions.

Comment: Hmm.. I'd prefer a way where I don't have to change the module code, as it can be anything: it is not that I want to protect some JS or CSS, but the modules do contain images, video's and documents that should not be public and only shown to authorised users (in fact for some resources it is illegal to show it to non-physicians).
Anyway, I will work my way around and use some mechanisms I have used before without Laravel routing.